# Strapi default logs in the console loses formatting

Tags: logging, strapi, winston

I customize the logger in middleware, written as follows:

```
const colors = {
  error: 'black redBG',
  warn: 'black yellowBG',
  info: 'black greenBG',
  http: 'black magentaBG',
  verbose: 'black cyanBG',
  debug: 'black blueBG',
  silly: 'black whiteBG',
};

winston.addColors(colors);

logFormat = printf(info => {
  const {
    timestamp,
    message,
    level,
    label,
    error,
    ...rest
  } = info;
  const printLabel = label ? `[${label}] ` : ' ';
  let log = `${timestamp} ${printLabel}${level} ${message}`;

  if (error) {
    log = error.stack ? `${log}\n${error.stack}` : log;
  }

  log += ' ' + JSON.stringify(rest);
  return log;
});
logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: combine(
    timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    prettyPrint(),
  ),
  defaultMeta: {
    service: name
  },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: combine(
        winston.format(info => {
          info.level = ` ${info.level.toUpperCase()} `;
          return info;
        })(),
        colorize(),
        logFormat,
      ),
    }),
  ],
});
```

When I call the logger function, the following picture will appear.

[Custom Logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQVsv.png)

However, I found that Strapi's original logger did not have the same effect.

[Default Logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UTfi.png)

For http logger, do I need to have additional configuration?